# TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm currently using Angular Forms version 2.0.0 and trying to make a contact us modal with a contact form inside.

Immediately after the ContactComponent loads, I get:

> EXCEPTION: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function

[image: Can't fine this.form._updateTreeValidity]

1. I've already seen some other stack posts suggesting that using FormGroup instead of FormBuilder to init the form object in the component constructor is now standard with the new API so I've updated that.
2. I import ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule along with all the form related components and the error doesn't seem to be module related.
3. My TypeScript isn't throwing errors in compile time and Visual Studio Intellisense seems to be able to find all FormGroup functions just fine so why is this happening at runtime?...

My code:

contact.component.ts:

```ts
import { Component, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../../services/api.service';
import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'my-contact',
    templateUrl: 'app/modules/footer/contact/contact.html'
})
export class ContactComponent {

    private contactForm: FormGroup;
    private invalidEmail: boolean;
    private invalidSubject: boolean;
    private invalidMessage: boolean;

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.contactForm = new FormGroup({
            emailControl: new FormControl('', <any>Validators.required),
            subjectControl: new FormControl('', <any>Validators.required),
            messageControl: new FormControl('', <any>Validators.required)
        });
    }

    submit() {

        if (this.contactForm.valid) {
            this.apiService.sendMessage(this.contactForm.controls['emailControl'].value, this.contactForm.controls['subjectControl'].value, this.contactForm.controls['messageControl'].value);
        }

        if (!this.contactForm.controls['emailControl'].valid) {
            this.invalidEmail = true;
        }
        if (!this.contactForm.controls['subjectControl'].valid) {
            this.invalidSubject = true;
        }
        if (!this.contactForm.controls['messageControl'].valid) {
            this.invalidMessage = true;
        }

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.invalidEmail = false;
        this.invalidSubject = false;
        this.invalidMessage = false;
    }

}
```

contact.html:

```html
<modal-header class="c-no-border" [show-close]="true">
  <h4 class="modal-title text-uppercase">Send us a message</h4>
</modal-header>

<form novalidate #contactForm [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
      <input name="email" formControlName="emailControl" placeholder="" type="text" class="c-square form-control c-margin-b-20" id="email">
      <div class="c-font-red-1" *ngIf="invalidEmail" style="position: absolute;">*Required</div>
      <label for="subject" class="control-label">Subject</label>
      <input name="subject" formControlName="subjectControl" placeholder="" type="text" class="c-square form-control c-margin-b-20" id="subject">
      <div class="c-font-red-1" *ngIf="invalidSubject" style="position: absolute;">*Required</div>
      <textarea formControlName="messageControl" style="resize: vertical;" class="c-square form-control c-margin-b-20" id="content" (keyup.enter)="submit()"></textarea>
      <div class="c-font-red-1" *ngIf="invalidMessage" style="position: absolute;">*Required</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <modal-footer class="c-no-padding">
    <button type="button" class="btn c-btn-square c-btn-bold c-btn-uppercase pull-right">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-square c-btn-bold c-btn-uppercase pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px;">Send</button>
  </modal-footer>
</form>
```

app.module.ts:

```ts
import { NgModule, enableProdMode }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Ng2Bs3ModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { QueuesModule }     from './modules/queues/queues.module';
import { OrderModule }     from './modules/order/order.module';
import { AccountModule } from './modules/account/account.module';
import { AdminModule } from './modules/admin/admin.module';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { SplashComponent } from './modules/splash/splash.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './modules/footer/contact/contact.component';

import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { EmailValidator } from './shared/utilities/custom-validators'

import { CookieService } from 'angular2-cookie/services/cookies.service';
import { HttpModule, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { StringService } from './services/string.service';
import { ApiService } from './services/api.service';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { OrderService } from './services/order.service';
import { OrderGuard } from './services/order-guard.service';
import { FooterComponent } from './modules/footer/footer.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './modules/error/error.component';
import { CustomFormsModule } from "ng2-validation";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        QueuesModule,
        OrderModule,
        AccountModule,
        AdminModule,
        routing,
        GridModule,
        SharedModule,
        Ng2Bs3ModalModule,
        CustomFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SplashComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        ErrorComponent,
        ContactComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        StringService,
        ApiService,
        UserService,
        CookieService,
        OrderService,
        OrderGuard
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    exports: [
    ]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Binding the template variable `#contactForm` appears to cause a name conflict and blow up the template processor. Also, if you're writing a model driven form it is advisable to only import `ReactiveFormsModule` to enforce only writing reactive forms.

It becomes more apparent when you don't have the double import that the template variable bind is the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it!

Comment: Yeah I knew that FormsModule seemed redundant, but I had it in there for good measure. I guess I won't use both now that there seem to be conflicts.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Binding the template variable `#contactForm` appears to cause a name conflict and blow up the template processor as it tries to turn the attached template variable into an `NgForm` on the backend. Everywhere I have seen model driven forms used there is no template variable binding on the form, whereas there is a `#tv="ngForm"` utilized in template driven forms. It appears there was a miss on the mixing of the two forms approaches which resulted in the error.

Simply removing it will resolve the issue.

Comment: To add to this, a great resource for others who might be having issues would be this github thread, which discusses other viable solutions: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22425#issuecomment-368288181

Answer (score 32):

When you incorrectly add to your template `formGroup="..."` instead of `[formGroup]="..."` you'll also get this error message.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the error is thrown when I incorrectly use the HTML attribute on the template:

```html
<form formGroup="..."></form>
```

We should be using the Angular attribute instead:

```html
<form [formGroup]="..."></form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometime this error is caused when you use a `[formGroup]` to pass the string of the **formGroup** name. Use `formGroupName` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had a dynamic form. I got above error since I didn't init it inside the `ngOnInit()`

***Solution:***

```
checkInForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(){
    this.checkInForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, but for me the problem was passing the formGroup to the template instead of referencing it directly.

E.g. this is **not working**

```
<ng-template #selectField
             let-field
             let-group
             let-frmName="frmName">
    <ng-container [formGroup]="group">
        <mat-form-field fxFlex="32"
                        floatLabel="always">
            <mat-label>{{field.label}}</mat-label>
            <mat-select [formControlName]="frmName"
                        [required]="field.required">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of field.options"
                            [value]="option.value">
                    {{option.description}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </ng-container>
</ng-template>
```

If I use directly my `formGroup` instance it works just fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when you're using the input name `formControl` or `formGroup` on a custom component which isn't a form control.

Change your custom component to accept a different input name:

#### Change this

```
@Input()
formGroup: string
// ^ Causes issues
```

#### To this

```
@Input()
group: string
```

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to pass my form to the reusable input `<app-input [form]="myForm"></app-input>`

app-input.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input [type]="type" [placeholder]="placeholder [formControlName]="formControlName" />
</form>
```

app-input.component.ts

```
  @Input() type: string = '';
  @Input() placeholder: string = '';
  @Input() formControlName: string = ''
  @Input() form: FormGroup = {} as FormGroup;
```