# Ionic 3 Reactive Forms in IonViewDidLoad or ionViewWillEnter not working

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, angular5, angular-reactive-forms

Ionic 3 Reactive Form is not working in IonViewDidLoad or ionViewWillEnter. It says

```
UserInfoPage.html:18 ERROR TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function
```

Whereas if I put form builder code in the Ionic Page's constructor then it says

```
UserInfoPage.html:23 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dateOfBirth' of undefined
```

I am using Lazy Loading for the form page. Please help and guide. Here's the complete code:

**user-info.ts:**

```
export class UserInfoPage {

  createForm(): any {
    this.userInfoForm = this.fb.group({
      dateOfBirth: [ '', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(new RegExp("(0[123456789]|10|11|12)([/])([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])"))]) ],
      weight: [ '', Validators.required, Validators.compose([Validators.pattern(new RegExp("[0-9]*"))]) ],
      height: [ '', Validators.required, Validators.compose([Validators.pattern(new RegExp("[0-9]*"))]) ],
    });
  }

  @ViewChild("userInfoForm") content: Content;

  userInfoForm: FormGroup;
  isFormLoaded: boolean;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private fb: FormBuilder, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.isFormLoaded = false;    
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.createForm();
    this.isFormLoaded = true;
    this.content.resize();    
  }

}
```

and

**user-info.html:**

```
<ion-content #userInfoForm>
  <form [formGroup]="userInfoForm" *ngIf="isFormLoaded">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-list-header>Please Enter Your Following Information</ion-list-header>    
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary" floating>Date of Birth</ion-label>
        <ion-input [formControl]="userInfoForm.controls['dateOfBirth']" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary" floating>Weight</ion-label>
        <ion-input [formControl]="userInfoForm.controls['weight']" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary" floating>Height</ion-label>
        <ion-input [formControl]="userInfoForm.controls['height']" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

ionic and angular newbie here. Thanks.

Comment: could you try naming #userInfoForm as something else?

Comment: Best use it in ionViewDidLoad. Also userInfoForm is both a template variable and component variable. It might be the reason for error.

Comment: thanks so much that was exactly the problem with my code.

Comment: I am glad it worked :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best use it in ionViewDidLoad. Also userInfoForm is both a template variable and component variable. It might be the reason for error.

Another similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40900504/2120711