# Nested angular forms can't find FormGroup

Tags: angular, nested-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I've got the template under *ngIf and it only generates after the form is loaded. Additionally, I've got the failing form under a dynamically displayed field, which depends on a button press. I log out the form, and it returns the FormControl which is missing correctly.

Template:

```
<div *ngIf="ready">
 <form [formGroup]="form">
        <div [formGroup]="form.controls.request">
          <div *ngFor="let field of inputFields">
            ...
          </div>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="somethingEnabled">
          <div [formGroup]="form.controls.Something">
            <div class="input-container">
              <label>Name: </label>
              <input formControlName="Name">
            </div>

            <div [formGroup]="form.controls.Something.Organization">

              <div class="input-container">
                <label>ASD: </label>
                <input formControlName="ASD">
              </div>

              <div [formGroup]="form.controls.Something.Organization.Other">
                <div class="input-container">
                  <label>Id: </label>
                  <input formControlName="Id">
                </div>

                <div [formGroup]="form.controls.Something.Organization.Other.SchmeNm">

                  <div class="input-container">
                    <label>SchmeName: </label>
                    <input formControlName="SchmeName">
                  </div>

                  <div class="input-container">
                    <label>SchmeValue: </label>
                    <input formControlName="SchmeValue">
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

code:

```
 generateForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      request: this.fb.group(
        this.generateRequestFields())
      ,
      Something: this.fb.group(this.generateSomething()),
      address: this.fb.group(
        this.generateAddress()
      )
    });
  }

  generateSomething() {
    const returnObject = {};
    returnObject['Name'] = new FormControl();
    returnObject['Organization'] = this.fb.group(this.generateOrganization());
    return returnObject;
  }

  generateOrganization() {
    const returnObject = {};
    returnObject['ASD'] = new FormControl();
    returnObject['Other'] = this.fb.group({
      Id: new FormControl(),
      Schme: this.fb.group({
        SchmeName: new FormControl(),
        ShcmeValue: new FormControl()
      }),
      Issr: new FormControl()
    });
    return returnObject;
  }
```

I only get the error when activating the **form.controls.something** part.
It works fine if I remove **form.controls.Something.Organization** part of the template.

Error:
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

I might have just missed something, and was hoping I'll find it while posting this, but still can't seem to get it

Answer (score 1):

For nested formGroups, use `formGroupName` not `formGroup`.

Comment: @TomasKsnauskas If my answer helped you solve this, please consider accepting the answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside a formGroup you don't need to access the controls of the parents form to define it's child form group, you can just use the name

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
        <div [formGroup]="request">
          <div *ngFor="let field of inputFields">
            ...
          </div>
```

Comment: I get **this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function** if i remove the nesting

Comment: This might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898056/typeerror-this-form-updatetreevalidity-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you `console.log(this.form.controls.Something.Organization)` it will also return undefined. For every FormGroup you add, you have to access its controls first and then move on to the next level, as in:

```
<div [formGroup]="form.controls.Something.controls.Organization">
 ...
   <div [formGroup]="form.controls.Something.controls.Organization.controls.Other">
    ...
```

Try it. If it doesn't work (can't access `Something`), also try:

```
<div [formGroup]="form.get("Something").get("Organization")">
```

`form.controls` will browse through the exact path you define, while `form.get` will go to the exact control you specify, making it useful for multilayered forms for ease of maintenance and reading.

Let us know what you get.