# *ngFor for JSON array

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ngfor

I've the following JSON struct

```
{
"first_name": "Peter",
"surname": "Parker",
"adresses": {
    "adress": [{
        "info1": "intern",
        "info2": "bla1"
    }, {
        "info1": "extern",
        "info2": "bla2"
    }, {
        "info1": "group",
        "info2": "bla3"
    }, {
        "info1": "outdoor",
        "info2": "bla4"
    }, {
        "info1": "indoor",
        "info2": "bla5"
    }]
}}
```

Q: How can i make a *ngFor about all addesses?

Thanks in advance and regards Filout

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this

in ts file

```
this.adressList= data.adresses.adress
```

in html file

```
<div *ngFor="let adress of adressList">
   {{adress.info1}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

do like this.

in your component.ts file

```
data = {
    "first_name": "Peter",
    "surname": "Parker",
    "adresses": {
        "adress": [{
            "info1": "intern",
            "info2": "bla1"
        }, {
            "info1": "extern",
            "info2": "bla2"
        }, {
            "info1": "group",
            "info2": "bla3"
        }, {
            "info1": "outdoor",
            "info2": "bla4"
        }, {
            "info1": "indoor",
            "info2": "bla5"
        }]
    }
  }
  address = this.data.adresses.adress
```

in html

```
<div *ngFor="let value of address">
  {{value.info1}} - {{value.info2}}
</div>
```

let me know if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick reply.
But what does *ERROR TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function* mean in the following code?

```
<div *ngFor="let address of addressList">
    <div [formGroup]="address">
      <input formControlName="info1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please check this link for more info on this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898056/typeerror-this-form-updatetreevalidity-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

I read that but i don't understand the solution.
I tried the following in ".ts":

```
constructor(...) {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group(...)
    this.formGroup.addControl('addresses', this.fb.group({
        address: new FormArray([])
    }))
```

That works for me.
Than i've another function like this:

```
public get objControl(): FormArray {
        return this.formGroup.controls.addresses.controls.address as FormArray
    }
```

If i set a breakpoint in constructor i can see `this.formGroup.controls.addresses.controls.address` with values but my IDE (Webstorm) say "Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'"

Why this?